# python .pyc file with win32com

Tags: python, win32com, typelib

I have a project that uses COM and 'Python' scripting. Earlier we were using 'ComTypes' now we use Win32Com. To keep backward compatibility I need to change name of some of the interfaces. So here is what I do

1) Use the 'makepy' utility to create a python file from my .tlb file, this creates a .py file at ..\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py folder

2) I change the name of the interface that I am interested in changing in the created python file.

3) When I load my application a corresponding .pyc file gets created and everything works fine.

Now I don't want to repeat this exercise on every machine where my software is deployed. So through the installer I copy the .py and .pyc files to ..\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py

But when my application is launched it does not recognize the changed interface. Behaves as if there is no .py or .pyc file. All other interfaces work, but the changed name one does not work. It dynamically seem to create compiled python behind the scene, ignoring the .pyc file.

If I delete the .dat file and .pyc file at those locations, it does create the .pyc file again when the application is launched. However its not utilized, because my changed interface does not work.

If I use the steps 1,2 and 3 everything works again !! I am puzzled.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found out what is the problem. When you create a python file using makepy tool it updates the dicts.dat file in gen_py directory. So you need to copy over that file as well to other machines.